# Writing a 'non-readable' list

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list readable only if a flag is `True`. If the flag is `False`, the list would appear as if it was empty. I wonder if this would be the right way to go about it?

```
def values(self):
    for v in self.items:
        if self.flag:
            yield v
        else:
            yield None
```

I don't think this is right, because if the flag was `False`, wouldn't the cursor continue to progress along `self.items` until it reaches the end? I'd like the cursor to 'freeze' when the flag is `False` so that when it's flipped next time, the element after the one returned when the flag was last True can be returned.

Note: `self.items` is a generator yielding from a massive file.

Thanks

Comment: Why yield each value? Just return the items at once as a list rather than a generator.

Comment: That's because self.items is supposed to be yielding from a massive file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of ways to implement what you're asking for. Here's one:

```
def values(self):
    for v in self.items:
        while not self.flag:
            yield None
        yield v
```

Comment: So, each time values is called when the flag is False, wouldn't the cursor move along self.items? Or does the cursor only shift along if the element is yielded?

Comment: When the flag is false, you're going to be stuck in the nested `while` loop. This code will report each element of `items` once, and will insert some number of extra `None` depending on the state of `self.flag`.

Comment: Right. But could would my version (using an if) not work as expected? Why does it have to be a loop?

Comment: Your version will skip elements of `self.items` when `self.flag` is `false`. The text of your question makes it seem that you don't want that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`my_lst_` will appear as empty when flag is `False` or an iterator if flag is `True`.

```
l = [1, 2, 3]    

class C(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = False

    def f(self):
        if self.flag is True:
            for i in l:
                yield i
        else:
            return []    

inst = C()
my_lst = inst.f()

print('\nFlag is False')
for i in my_lst:
    print(i)

# Set the flag to true and create new iterator.
inst.flag = True
my_lst = inst.f()

print('\nFlag is True')
for i in my_lst:
    print(i)
```